# How can i let sql server 2008 accept the date 2003/2/29

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have date `29/2/2003` but when i export it to table in my database the system convert it to `Null` so how can i let `SQL SERVER 2008` accept the date `2003/2/29` ?

Comment: Why would it accept an invalid date?

Comment: 2003 is not a leap year. There's no Feb 29, 2003. How did that enter your dataset in the first place?

Comment: obviously there is no Feb 29,2003 in database

Comment: Nobody lived in that day why you want to save it

Comment: Thanks very much about your comment's , i think the mistake from data entry .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert a date format that is not valid as : **2003/2/29** ,you will get the error as :

> String was not recognised as a valid DateTime

In order to save ,change the **datatype** to `nvarchar`

Comment: Nope I got this `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: @Indian actually OP wants to insert invalid data,i meant that would show error ..